# How to explain Read/Write global variables in multi threads environment

Tags: multithreading, global-variables, atomic

I am not familiar with multi-thread and locks and atomic/nonatomic operations.

Recently I saw an interview question as below.

Put `f1` and `f2` in two separate threads and run them at the same time, when both of them return, what is the value of `a`?

```
int a = 2, b = 0, c = 0
func f1()
{
    a = a * 2
    a = b
}
func f2()
{
    c = a + 11
    a = c
}
```

I tried to implement the above code in objective c environment and what I got is `a = 11`. I'm not sure if this is right since what I did is put `f1` in main queue and put `f2` in a dispatch global queue and ran it async which could be incorrect.

If someone could give an answer and explain the process based on the level of `register accessing`, `CPU processing`, `memory usage`, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - the result of A is random. It can be anything. Since access to A is not atomic and there is no synchronization, different threads might see a different value for a depending on random factors. If you manage to make a unaligned and run it on X86, you might even see a non-value for a.